# Problema de posición de elementos Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind

Buen día recién estoy aprendiendo a usar `Tailwind CSS` y tengo esta duda, en el código quiero alinear las `cards` y el texto de manera vertical uno con respecto al otro, pero por más que pongo clases para mover cualquiera de los dos se sobreponen o no se mueven de donde están:

Podrían decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

```html
<div class="relative flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-full">
  <div class="hero-content flex-row lg:flex-row-reverse">
    <div class="flex ml-200">
      <!--CARD1-->
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
        <div class="group relative cursor-pointer items-center justify-center overflow-hidden transition-shadow hover:shadow-xl hover:shadow-black/30">
          <div class="h-96 w-72">
            <img class="h-full w-full object-cover transition-transform duration-500 group-hover:rotate-3 group-hover:scale-125" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494145904049-0dca59b4bbad?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=688&q=80"
              alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-b from-transparent via-transparent to-black group-hover:from-black/70 group-hover:via-black/60 group-hover:to-black/70">
          </div>
          <div class="absolute inset-0 flex translate-y-[60%] flex-col items-center justify-center px-9 text-center transition-all duration-500 group-hover:translate-y-0">
            <h1 class="font-dmserif text-3xl font-bold text-white">
              Concursos
            </h1>
            <p class="mb-3 text-lg italic text-white opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-300 group-hover:opacity-100">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis dolore adipisci placeat.
            </p>
            <!--CARD 2-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group relative cursor-pointer items-center justify-center overflow-hidden transition-shadow hover:shadow-xl hover:shadow-black/30">
          <div class="h-96 w-72">
            <img class="h-full w-full object-cover transition-transform duration-500 group-hover:rotate-3 group-hover:scale-125" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494145904049-0dca59b4bbad?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=688&q=80"
              alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-b from-transparent via-transparent to-black group-hover:from-black/70 group-hover:via-black/60 group-hover:to-black/70">
          </div>
          <div class="absolute inset-0 flex translate-y-[60%] flex-col items-center justify-center px-9 text-center transition-all duration-500 group-hover:translate-y-0">
            <h1 class="font-dmserif text-3xl font-bold text-white">Compite</h1>
            <p class="mb-3 text-lg italic text-white opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-300 group-hover:opacity-100">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis dolore adipisci placeat.
            </p>
            <button class="rounded-full bg-neutral-900 py-2 px-3.5 font-com text-sm capitalize text-white shadow shadow-black/60">
              See More
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--card 3 -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1 class="text-6xl font-bold text-white">¡BIENVENIDOS!</h1>
    <p class="py-6 text-white text-4xl">*bienvenido pagina principal*</p>

    <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center justify-start inline-block px-10 py-3 overflow-hidden font-medium transition-all bg-blue-600 rounded-full hover:bg-white group">
      <span class="absolute inset-0 border-0 group-hover:border-[25px] ease-linear duration-100 transition-all border-white rounded-full"></span>
      <span class="relative w-full text-left text-white transition-colors duration-600 ease-in-out group-hover:text-blue-600">Explorar</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```